# aggregating using 'gdalwarp -average' resulting in incorrect values

Tags: python, raster, gdal, linux

I'm trying to aggregate data up from 0.05 to a coarser 0.25 resolution and am having trouble getting gdalwarp to work correctly. From comparing the original input data with the aggregated data and manually calculating the averages, I can see that the result I'm getting is not what I would expect. Many (not all) aggregated pixel values are just wrong (FYI, I have specifically been looking where the water meets land on the horn of Africa). Also, it's my understanding that gdal is supposed to ignore NoData pixels in the average calculation, but in some areas, the 25 pixels underneath the aggregated pixels were all NoData, yet the aggregated pixel reported a number, when it should have been NoData.

The command I used below:

gdalwarp -tr .25 .25 -r average -srcnodata -15000 -dstnodata -15000 /path/to/temp_CHIRPS_201512.tif /path/to/CHIRPS_201512_ave.tif

I can post the entire script if need be.

I'm using gdal 2.0.1 on linux.

Here is a link to the input file I used, in addition to the result I got by calling the above command: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/dk0c41638jg8fir/AAD9z9IXeEfJ2PyEUVnjG4aya?dl=0

I tried running the same command on a different dataset (I am doing the same process for several datasets) and it appears gdalwarp did in fact work.

Can anyone help me understand why it is working for one dataset and not the other?

Comment: Interesting, do you have a representative datasource to reconstruct the behavior?

Comment: @huckfinn I do. How can I get it to you?

Comment: Download, Dropbox, Github

Comment: @huckfinn here is a link to the input file I used and the output I got with the above command: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/dk0c41638jg8fir/AAD9z9IXeEfJ2PyEUVnjG4aya?dl=0

Comment: Hi @huckfinn were you able to receive my data from drop box? Thanks so much!

Comment: Hi, yes I got the datasets and make some test. Which version of gdal do you use? I use version 1.10.1.

Comment: I was using 2.0.1 and now am using 2.0.2 which isn't working either. I have to use GDAL2+ so I can use the other resampling methods in addition to average. I also added an update which makes me think it's not GDAL, but the data. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think the index numbers for the row of the averaging window function is shifted and that seems to be an error. To get this opinion, I made the following test using QGIS and a subsample of the both datasets you left in the dropbox.

In first step I cut out a windows in the region of your interest ..some where to address an area in the northern part of the Red Sea:

```
gdal_translate -projwin 0 50 50 0 temp_CHIRPS_201512.tif hires.tif
gdal_translate -projwin 0 50 50 0 CHIRPS_201512_ave.tif lowres.tif
```

[image: subset maps]

I call the full resolution image `hires.tif` and the averaged one `lowres.tif`. To see what the `gdalwarp` tool produces I built xyz files to get frames and numbers corresponding to the cells

```
gdal_translate hires.tif hires.xyz -of xyz
gdal_translate lowres.tif lowres.xyz -of xyz
```

and import the stuff into QGIS via Layer -> Add Layer -> Add Delimited Text Layer with the following settings:

[image: import hires.xyz]

The same procedure was applied to the lowres stuff. I zoom to the paninsula of Sinai and set the symbology of the raster to a squared marker without background and a size of 0.05 map units for the hires positions and 0.25 map units for the lowres points (your produced raster sizes).

[image: raster and frames]

I choose colored symbology for the hires raster:

[image: hires raster settings]

and a gray setup for the lowres (averaged) raster to bring out the artefacts.

[image: lowres raster settings]

At 35° East and 27° North we find a nice artefact that should be a -15000 cell (NA in GNU-R speech).

[image: artefact region]

To see whats happend I zoom in and label the cells:

[image: wrong cell]

It seems, that we have a cell shift and the average is calculated from a wrong set of samples,

[image: shift window]

because if I use to north shifted window, I will calculate:

```
> cell <- c(
+   NA,  6, 27, 25, NA, 
+   NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
+   NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
+   NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
+   NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
+ );
> mean(cell,na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 19.33333
```

and get the magic `19` at a wrong place in the raster. I think you should send a bug report to the [gdal community](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/).

Sorry forgot to use python...

```
In [1]: import numpy

In [2]: cell = numpy.array ([
   ...:   None,  6, 27, 25, None, 
   ...:   None, None, None, None, None,
   ...:   None, None, None, None, None,
   ...:   None, None, None, None, None,
   ...:   None, None, None, None, None
   ...: ])

In [3]: numpy.mean(filter(None, cell))
Out[3]: 19.333333333333332
```

In this [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/jrsxye0ss24woz6/AAAoIf7pw1Fx6DpQtCJbkMnWa?dl=0) you will find the test environment with:

- `avg-error.qgs` the qgis project
- `temp_CHIRPS_201512.tif` your hires file
- `CHIRPS_201512_ave.tif` your lowres file
- `hires.tif` the 0 50 50 0 cut version of the hires file
- `hires.xyz` the xyz export of the hires cut version
- `lowres.tif` the cut version of the lowres file
- `lowres.xyz` the xyz export of the hires cut version
- `hires-point.qml` style to draw the cells hires.xyz
- `lowres-point.qml` style to draw the cells lowres.xyz
- `hires-raster.qml` style to draw the hires raster
- `lowres-raster.qml` style to draw the lowres raster
- `howto` code snippets

enjoy...

Comment: WOW. thank you. I'll review this in more detail later. Do you have any idea why it works for other inputs (different dataset) but not this one?

Comment: I just looked at my results and unfortunately I don't see the shift. Have you taken a look at the other raster I left on dropbox (the result I got)? Maybe we are getting different results. Thanks again.

Comment: Hm... strange. I use the **both** datasets from the dropbox and choose exactly the cell samples. The position of the cell with the value 6 is (35,05:27,8) (35,1:27,75)  in the file temp_CRISP_201512.tif.

Comment: I put the test environment in the dropbox https://www.dropbox.com/sh/jrsxye0ss24woz6/AAAoIf7pw1Fx6DpQtCJbkMnWa?dl=0. Look at the comments I added at the end of my answer...