# Displaying numbers of single band raster layer in QGIS without additional vector layer?

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-plugins

I wonder if there is a raster symbolizer in QGIS with a label option, that renders the **cell values** as labels of single band raster layer, a **scalar field**.

[image: raster cells with labels]

The standard raster symbolizer dialog in QGIS has no **label** option. So I use two data sources, a raster (geotiff) and a xyz-vector re-incarnation of the raster to draw the map. To be compatible with the GDAL cell addressing I use

```
   gdal_translate hires.tif hires-point.xyz -of xyz
```

and apply all the vector symbology and labeling capabilities on/to the xyz-object.

For large scalar fields, this workaround is **very slow** and **not handy**. At least I want to build a map for debugging purposes with this look.

[image]

Is there a plugin for QGIS that draws raster cells as shown above without the vector handicraft?

I use Debian Jessie Linux, QGIS Pisa 2.10 and gdal 2.0.1

I try to investigate the results of GDAL raster window operations for example (comment @Paulo).

Comment: Not exactly what you're asking for, but maybe do this with GDAL bindings for Python (and matplotlib), or R (and spatial)?

Comment: @Paulo, Yes GDAL and Python is always an option, but I've to build this test setup (http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/182309/26213), with many of steps and settings and a very slow environment. I want to use the options of  a raster symbolizer.

Comment: Not quite the answer you are looking for, but displaying would probably be as much time consuming with raster than with points. As you seem to work in integers and with relatively large patches, maybe you could polygonize your raster in order to have less features to label.

Comment: @radouxju Hm, I made an opposite expierence. I'ved tried to investigate some raster window calculation stuff in this Q&A context (http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/182309/26213) and started to label the cells here with the uncutted version of the full TIF temp_CHIRPS_201512.tif (7200x2000 cells). This process takes a very long time to import and label the 14.4 Mill points if no spatial index is present. The opeartion runs in a time scale of minutes. So I've cutted the material to a region of interest (1000x1000 cells) and get a handy setup for this example.

Comment: my point is that labelling each cel is inefficient. one large area of NaN just requires a single label in a vector based model, That being said I haven't tested it, so I am not sure that this is the best solution in your case (also depends on the number of patches) (therefore I do not put this as an answer)

Comment: @radouxju OK, but isn't this kind of efficeny a matter of scale in a context of displaying things and caching/indexing. I think, we have good  tools to paint, label, build and manipulate vectors (to vertext level) in QGIS, but for raster, these capabilities are limited to drawing, raster calculations and raster/vector op's.  Is it a matter of traditionell separated thinking of in 2D spatial types (raster/ vector/ graph) and the dawn of 3D GIS stuff?  Edit DEM's with advanced tools works also with limitations (speed/size) https://somethingaboutmaps.wordpress.com/2014/01/01/blender-tutorial/

Comment: Not an answer, but a workaround - have you tried using the Value Tool plugin? This will show the value of raster cells under the mouse cursor with live updating, and is independent of the active layer.

Comment: A potencial good and nice new feature for QGIS future version. Did you post to Dev list ?

Comment: @Azimo I've been thinking about it, but I was missing the time for a decent feature request.

Answer (score 5):

this would be a great feature.

In my dreams, I could also double-click on a raster cell and set its value...

SAGA GIS can render cells like this. These instructions are for SAGA GIS 2.2.6 . There have been a few menu changes in recent versions of SAGA, but this is also possible in older versions.

- Import your raster using **Geoprocessing > File > Grid > Import > Import Raster**
- In properties, check "Show cell values" then "Apply"
- Zoom right in

This screenshot shows the result...

[image]